# Prolog selecting elements from list of lists

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, accumulator

Given a list of lists (e.g., `[[1],[1,2,3],[3,4]]`) I want to create every possible permutation of the member of the sublists so the expected result from the mentioned example would look like:

```
?- get_elements([[1], [1,2,3], [3,4]], R).
R = [[1,1,3],[1,1,4],[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,3,3],[1,3,4]] ? ;
no
```

What I have is the following:

```
get_elements([], []).
get_elements([[H|_]|Lists], [H|L]) :-
    get_elements(Lists, L).
get_elements([[_,H|T]|Lists], L) :-
    get_elements([[H|T]|Lists], L).
```

This works great but returns the elements one by one, so the output is as follows:

```
?- get_elements([[1],[1,2,3],[3,4]], R).
R = [1,1,3] ? ; 
R = [1,1,4] ? ;
R = [1,2,3] ? ;
R = [1,2,4] ? ;
R = [1,3,3] ? ;
R = [1,3,4] ? ;
no
```

I guess I should add another parameter for accumulating the elements, but just can't clearly see how. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the layout cleanup @repeat !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `findall/3` to gather all the outputs:

Rename `get_elements/2` with something like `get_elements1/2` and add this procedure:

```
get_elements(L, R):-
  findall(E, get_elements1(L, E), R).
```